# On WP8, which assembly should I reference for MultiBinding class

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, multibinding

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx), `MultiBinding` class is supported on WP8.

Quote:

> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
>
> ...
>
> Platforms: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)

However, I am unable to find the phone version of `PresentationFramework.dll`. Some blog posts also suggest there is no `MultiBinding` on WP8. Is MSDN wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an error. I don't know about WP8.1, but the `IMultiValueConverter` interface definitely isn't available on WP8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a documentation error. `MultiBinding` is not available for Windows Phone 8.0 or 8.1.